# Using string offset from variable Error

Tags: php, arrays, variables, offset

I've been getting error from accessing array with string offsets. The array looks something like this:

```
$array = array(
                    "first" => array("one","two","three"),
                    "second" => array("blabla"),
                    "third" => array("something","else"),
                    "fourth" => array("next","nextnext","nextnextnext")
    );
```

I'm trying to get one of the inside arrays depending on string I have and I use that string as offset, like this:

```
$curArray = $array[$this->string];
```

But everytime I run the script I get an error on that line. Can you please tell me why?
The error I get is "Illegal offset type".
Thanks

Comment: What is `$this`? What is `$this->string`?

Comment: To call the third array for example you should use something like this `$curArray = $array["third"];`

Comment: well, the code is a part of function of a class, so `$this->string` reffers to value of $string property of the object

Comment: Try `var_dump($this->string);` and check what it contains

Comment: it contains in all  cases something like this `object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) { [0]=> string(3) "second" } `

Comment: var_dump($this->string); will give you its type, by just echoing it you wont be able to tell what type it is.

Comment: @MichalArtazov That object isn't a string so can't be used as a key. I've updated my answer but you should convert this to a string before using it as an array key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that `$this->string` isn't what you think it is. This error is caused by a non string or number being used as an array key.

if you do `var_dump($this->string);` You should be able to see what the value actually is.

Edit: 
A `SimpleXMLElement` is an object and therefore can't be used as an array key. You can cast it to a string like so:

```
$key = (string)$this->string;
$curArray = $array[$key];
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$this->string` is not recognized as an actual string value.

You may want to run a `print_r ( $this->string )` to get a better idea of what it contains.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

You can use the `is_string(..)` function to figure out of `$this->string` is valid, and perhaps check with `array_key_exists ()` if your lookup is valid.